# How to center a form on the screen (between navigation bar and footer)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First of all, this isn't a duplicated question. I checked all previous posted questions similar to this type of issue and I didn't find any solution for this specific scenario.

I'm using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction) <strike>and here is my app URL: https://loving-shaw-e78a46.netlify.com/auth/login</strike>

*(I share an URL because I don't know how to post the CSS and HTML of a React app, code is huge and Stack Overflow doesn't let me to post it because of the size limit)*.

So what I would like to do is:

1. Make `<main class="container">` fill all the height between the navigation bar and footer.
2. Center vertically `<div class="form-page">`.

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't downvote this question, I'm so sorry for not be able to post the CSS and HTML, I'm using `React` + `styled-components` and I don't know how to get the styles, to be honest. I read a lot about CSS Flexbox before post this question but I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used flexbox
I needed to overwrite some of your values

```
#app > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* overwrite */
body {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
footer.cmTXSD  {
  position: relative;
}
```

### Note

the `margin-bottom` overwrite 'deletes' your `margin-bottom: 313px;` 313px is like a magic number you did not calculate, but measured by experiment. This is a strong code smell in CSS. If you need to use magic numbers in CSS, try to think it over.

Comment: Amazing, thank you.

Comment: `margin-bottom: 313px` aka the magic number it was a way to make the footer "sticky" to the bottom haha. Here is the [Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Oh that d***d bootstrap: Sticky footer is easy: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/PyeRQx

Comment: Woahh, you're the man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with flexbox:

First you have to surround everything within a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100vh">
  // header
  // content
  // footer
</div>
```

The 100vh stands for view height. Now to make sure your content is the size of the page add flex: 1. That's the answer on your first question.

And to center it add justify-content-center and align-items-center.

So the end result should look like:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100vh">
  // header

  <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center" style="flex: 1">
    // content
  </div>

  // footer
</div>
```

This also means you don't have to force your footer down with position absolute or fixed.

Comment: Thanks tom, you're technically right but it didn't work at all with the code I provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add few css code to make the form look in the center of the container.
Please find below code and add to your css file.

```
     .container {height: calc(100vh - 383px);position: relative;}
     .container .form-page {position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 15px 30px;}
```

Thank You.